# Как перенаправить pip install Python в Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, manjaro

В данный момент установлена версия python 3.7.1(Основная)
в папке `/usr/bin/python`

pip установлен в папке :

```
/usr/bin/pip
```

версия : `pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Django установлен в папке

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages(1.6)
```

Как отвязать версию 3.7.1 и привязать версию 3.4.0, перенаправить pip?
Не удаляя python 3.7.1?

Например когда ставлю Django 1.6
командой `pip install django==1.6` он мне ставит в эту папку :

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.6)
```

Также есть две версии 
3.3.2 и 3.4.0 в папках и они установлены

```
/home/de/python/3.3.2
/home/de/python/3.4.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пип написан на питоне, в `/usr/bin/pip` только запускалка. Чаще всего она на питоне, но бывает ещё на баше.
Чтоб не путаться в версиях запускай так.

```
python3.4 -m pip install pkg
```

Естественно `pip` должен быть установлен в старом питоне. `python3.4` - симлинк на нужный питон.

```
sudo ln -s /home/de/python/3.4.0/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python3.4
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/python3.4
```

Или установите его в систему

```
sudo make altinstall
```

Pip установить проще [через установщик](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) в вашем случае.

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.4 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86304/discussion-on-answer-by-eri---pip-install-python--linux).

Answer (score 2):

```
Os :  Manjaro Linux 18.0.0 
Архив : Python-3.5.0.tgz
стартовая_папка: /home/de

1. Перед этим всем ставлю пакет sudo pacman -S openssl

2. Качаем : wget python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/Python-3.5.0.tgz 

3. Распаковываем : tar -xf Python-3.5.0.tgz  появилась папка адрес --->>>  /home/de/Python-3.5.0

3.5 cd Python-3.5.0

4. Конфигурация папки и pip upgrade :  ./configure --prefix=$HOME/python/3.5.0   --with-ensurepip=upgrade
configure - это скрипт. и лежит он в исходниках
а ./configure - это запуск этого скрипта

5. Установка make &&  make altinstall

6. Удаление старой ссылки sudo unlink /usr/local/bin/python3.5

7. Создаем симлинк sudo ln -s /home/de/python/3.5.0/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/python3.5

7.5 Проверяем python3.5 -V

8. Даем права sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/python3.5

9. Далее curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
   Описание curl  https://losst.ru/kak-polzovatsya-curl#_curl

10.  python3.5 get-pip.py
```